# remove from list and comparator java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have to remove element from list
but by only comparing it's ID ( variable in class)
so I implemented comparable in my class
but its not removing

```
class data implements Comparable<data>{
  int id;
  int data;

  data(int i,int d) {
    id=i;
    data=d;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(data o) {
    if(id==o.id)
      return 0;
    return -1;
  }
}

public class trial {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<data> newone =  new ArrayList<>();
    data o1= new data(1,2);
    data o2= new data(1,3);
    System.out.println("Added");
    newone.add(o1);
    System.out.println(o1.id);
    System.out.println(o2.id);
    if(newone.contains(o2)) {
      newone.remove(o2);
      System.out.println("found");
    }
    if(newone.isEmpty())
    System.out.println("Deleted");
    System.out.println("finsihed");
}
```

Comment: thank you everyone
did that
@Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  if(obj instanceof data){
   data input=(data)obj;
   if(id==input.id)
    return true;
  }
  return false;
 }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate the list using `Iterator` class and then use **remove** method to remove the element otherwise you can face some issues 'concurrent Modification Exception'.

Also `contains` method of ArrayList use the `equals` method of the element of the list,So you need to implement the **equals** method in the class `Data`

Answer (score 2):

you need to override equals method...

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return id==obj.id;
}
```